# What does -n in python represent?

Tags: python, argparse

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Meow like a cat")
parser.add_argument("-n", default=1,help="number of times to meow", type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()

for _ in range(arg.n):
    print("meow")
```

I don't really understand the purpose of having -n in line 4, I know it's a value holder for command line argument, but why -n; is there a special meaning to it? Also, why in the for loop, the parameter takes arg.n instead of arg.-n since that's what it used before? Thank You for helping!

Comment: `-n` is an invalid Python name. The dash is just standard for an argument that's a single letter. Ones that have longer names have two dashes, like `--number`. The dashes are not part of the arg's name. The name is `n`. I'm guessing in this case `n` is short for `number`. But it's just a matter of preference and what makes sense.

Comment: You should read the manual for `argparse`. You're creating a command line argument `-n` which you can use when you run the program from the command line. In unix, command line arguments start with `-` or `--`. When you run the program with the argument, argparse grabs the argument and stores it for use

Comment: There is no universal meaning of `n` but it often stands for number

Answer (score 2):

`add_argument("-n", ...)` defines an argument that takes '-n'` as a flag, and is used as with

```
$python your_script -n 1
```

`argparse` sets that value to the `args` object.

```
print(args)
Namespace(n=1)
```

which is then accessed as

```
args.n
```

All that should be explained in the `argparse` docs.

'n' is called the `dest`, and is derived from the `add_argument` option-string by stripping off the dash.

```
 add_argument('-n','--number', ...)
```

would set the `dest` to 'number', but accept either

```
 myscript -n 1
 myscript --number 3
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a convention of passing arguments to programs, not a Python thing per se. So usually it's `-{single-letter}` or `--{a word}`. So `-n` would be the same as `--number` in that case

Answer (score 1):

Command-line tools have two kinds of arguments: flags/options (denoted by either a single or double dash, in this case `-n` but could also be something like `--version`) and positional arguments which are just data (for example a path). You can find one explanation of them [here](http://www.acadix.biz/Unix-guide/HTML/ch01s07.html).

You can find documentation on argparse on [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) that showcases what kind of options you have for different types of arguments and how they are translated into the resulting Python object.